# Is there a way to search Drupal's and contrib modules configuration settings?

Tags: 7, search, configuration

With so many different modules in use with configuring Drupal it is hard to keep track of which settings are configured where, such as whether some CSS is set by the [Code per Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/cpn) or [CSS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector).

It would be nice to have search pinpoint what configuration settings contain some keyword. Does search have such a facility? I understand that the search module is mainly used by content such as nodes and entities.

But is there some way something like this can be accomplished, even by some module, or do module developers need to configure their modules settings to be indexable by search?

Comment: Most would say this is trackable with Features, but only browseable via code. Someone may have built a UI?

Comment: You could search the variables table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful fact: `drush vget abc` lists all variables with 'abc' in their name. So if you are looking for settings related to css, `drush vget css` might provide you with a clue. Likewise you can use the name of a module in your search to see all the settings from that module.

Some modules have complex settings that are stored in separate database tables. In that case I recommend using a tool such as SQLyog that has a search facility which will scan an entire database, or just specific tables, for a given input string.